# Log4j Issue RollingFileAppender maxBackupIndex, maxSize, gap between index

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I’m using log4j (1.2.14) for logging external data. It is information that could not be sent over the network to other applications.

I have a RollingFileAppender with  maxSize and maxBackupIndex.

The logging process works fine. The process creates files as:

```
file.out
file.out1
file.out2
..
..
file.out[maxBackupIndex]
```

The problem is that I have another process periodically (when the logging process is off) send and delete (locally) some file to another location.

For example:
original files list:

```
file.out
file.out1
file.out2
file.out3
file.out4
```

The process sends and deletes file.out1, file.out2.

new files list:

```
file.out
file.out3
file.out4
```

Now, the logging process starts again.. Then log4j maintains the “gap” of 2 files… log4j creates:

```
file.out
file.out1
file.out4 (content of file.out3)
file.out5 (content of file.out4)
```

The problem is when maxBackupIndex is reached. Log4j not completes the gap with free space and begins overwriting the contents of my older files.

Comment: Seems to work as designed. Why can't your other process that deletes the files, rename the remaining files accordingly?

Comment: Yes, renaming remaining files is a good option.